# Wifi hotspot and Flashlight

Tags: wifi-hotspot, camera-flash

I am being told by my device (HTC one E8) that the camera flash (and thereby flashlight app) and portable wifi hotspot cannot work at the same time.

I dont see any logical connection between the two, question is can anyone explain the reason this is happening and any workarounds/alternatives

Comment: For comparison, stock Lollipop on Nexus 4 doesn't have this limitation (I could turn on both, no warning at all), but it's true that the device became so hot. So I believe this is more of a custom safety precaution by HTC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of those functions consume a large amount of energy. The phone's processor and other components require a minimum amount of energy to remain stable. The battery can only output so much at a time. The phone is not letting you use both simultaneously time to avoid a "brown-out" and potential crash or other failure (perhaps it is unsafe for the battery as well, overheating is dangerous). Many phones also restrict the use of the flash when battery power is very low.

If you use a third party flashlight app, you *may* be able to bypass the restriction. I know I can, however my phone is also rooted which makes everything easier.

Comment: I agree with you that this is a plausible explanation, I will wait for other more convincing answers and accept if none exist

Answer (score 0):

Wi-Fi and Bluetooth for my HTC One E9  cannot function unless I install a flash light app. I don't know how they are related,but have read several articles advising users to install the app as solution to faulty Wi-Fi.it works